# Sveltekit with Superbase __api not defined

Tags: authentication, svelte, sveltekit

I have successfully run superbase with svelte using this [tutorial](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-svelte) . However I really need the sveltkit rather than basing it on the [svelte template](https://svelte.dev/blog/the-easiest-way-to-get-started) . When I try to use superbase based on a sveltkit project I get the following error

```
11:50:01 [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/superbaseClient.js:
ReferenceError: __api is not defined
    at /src/superbaseClient.js:3:21
    at async instantiateModule (/Users/bob/Documents/dev/javascript/svelte/svelteBp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-971d9e33.js:56177:9)
11:50:01 [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/routes/sbase.svelte:
ReferenceError: __api is not defined
    at /src/superbaseClient.js:3:21
    at async instantiateModule (/Users/bob/Documents/dev/javascript/svelte/svelteBp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-971d9e33.js:56177:9)
__api is not defined
ReferenceError: __api is not defined
    at /src/superbaseClient.js:3:21
    at async instantiateModule (/Users/bob/Documents/dev/javascript/svelte/svelteBp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-971d9e33.js:56177:9)
```

I have tried

1. Created a new sveltkit project using the [sveltkit getting started instructions](https://kit.svelte.dev/)
2. Followed the getting started instructions in [superbase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-svelte) but replaced the use of the svelte template with a sveltekit project.
3. Installed superbase with  https://github.com/supabase-community/svelte-supabase
4. I ignored the lines about installing the rollup plugins in the guide because I believe they are covered off by svelte kit.

More code is available for the whole [project on the github](https://github.com/PaulAyling/svelteKitBoilerPlate). The code with all my failed attempts at getting it to work can be found in a branch on that repo called "add superbase"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the Supabase Adder: https://github.com/supabase-community/svelte-supabase

Comment: Thanks I have tried Supabase Adder (which worked after I upgraded node.js)Hoever I now have a differnet issue when I run the app I get the following error (added to the original post)

Comment: All good I had to update my version of node to get the plugin to work. It works with svelte perfectly now. I completed a repo that uses svelte , superbase and tailwind to managage a simple todo app here https://github.com/PaulAyling/svleltkit-superbase-todo